# Fix order of window buttons in xfce panel

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel

Soon after installing Xubuntu, I moved the default dock from the bottom of the screen to the left, and added a regular panel in the bottom with the window list.

However, as I open windows, the window list doesn't show them in order. I expected them to be sorted from left to right, newer ones on the right, but this doesn't happen.

How can I make the panel sort the windows correctly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do this: right-click on the panel, navigate to **Panel > Panel Preferences...**, then change to the **Items** tab, and select the **Window Buttons** item. Click the settings button, and in the dialog that opens, change the **Sorting order** dropdown menu to "Timestamp". That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for this! Also, I like the "None, Allow Drag and Drop" option (which is more like Lucid).

Comment: Yes, and that option seems to use the timestamp by default, do it's win-win :D

Comment: Great man! Thanks! I was suffering from this issue about half of year!